# API to receive notifications for *all* file modifications on an entire Windows filesystem?

Tags: java, c++, windows, winapi, filesystems

I've searched StackOverflow and elsewhere and haven't found anything appropriate for my needs.

I don't want a polling solution, it needs to be event driven and to receive every such event in (near) real-time. The only data I need from the event object is the path/name of the modified (or created, or deleted) file.

Please note, I don't want to receive events for a specific file or directory, I want to receive events for an entire volume (eg "C:" - not required to support network drives!).

Ideally I'm looking for a Java API, but I suspect none exists, so I'm happy to write wrappers to C/C++.

NB, if this is possible from just the Windows command prompt or WMI that would be great too!

Comment: OT on So. BTW take a look at [this interesting article](https://lwn.net/Articles/604686/)

Comment: @LPs unforutnatelly, that's linux-only.

Comment: @Shark so [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch2s8yd7(v=vs.90).aspx) can help..

Comment: @LPs indeed, it looks like you debunked the OPs "I searched everywhere" statement :D

Comment: Downvoted why? And Shark's second "solution" (which I had found) is C#, not a viable solution, since as was clearly stated I need to be able to interop from Java.

Comment: A kernel-mode filesystem filter is your friend. As you can't write one in Java, you have to either create one in C, or use our CallbackFilter that includes a pre-created driver for your use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `FindFirstChangeNotification`.  Specify the root of the volume, and specify that you want to be notified for changes to the subdirectory too.  Then wait on the notification handle, and read the changes with `ReadDirectoryChanges`.

See this example from Microsoft:

[Obtaining Directory Change Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx)

(Note, I found that with 10 seconds of searching for "windows file watcher" - you may find some of the other links there helpful if you want a non C or C++ solution.)

Comment: Hm, I tried "listener", "observer" and "monitor", not watcher!

Comment: That API method doesn't actually monitor file changes, just directories. To actually determine what file had changed, I would need to maintain a map of every single file's last modified timestamp in memory, and compare each file in the directory's timestamp to the one in memory, unless I have missed something? Not really practical, I fear:(

Comment: @barneypitt: you missed this statement in the `FindFirstChangeNotification()` documentation (and which Martin's answer above also says): "*This function does not indicate the change that satisfied the wait condition. **To retrieve information about the specific change as part of the notification, use the [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465.aspx) function**.*" That function does give you actual filenames of added/removed/renamed/modified files.

Answer (score 0):

Call [SHChangeNotifyRegister](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762120.aspx) with the last parameter set to NULL.